# Prove that $\frac{2cos(2^n\theta)+1}{2cos\theta+1}= (2cos\theta -1)(2cos2\theta -1)(2cos2^2\theta -1)...(2cos2^{n-1}\theta -1)$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that

$$\frac{2cos(2^n\theta)+1}{2cos\theta+1}= (2cos\theta -1)(2cos2\theta -1)(2cos2^2\theta -1)...(2cos2^{n-1}\theta -1)$$

How do i do this

thanks

Comment: Do you have anything that you have tried...

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for induction

Comment: @Riemann-bitcoin. can you show me some start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
(2cos\theta+1)(2cos\theta -1)(2cos2\theta -1)(2cos2^2\theta -1)...(2cos2^{n-1}\theta -1)=
$$
$$
(2cos2\theta+1)(2cos2\theta -1)(2cos2^2\theta -1)...(2cos2^{n-1}\theta -1)=
$$
$$
(2cos4\theta+1)(2cos4\theta -1)(2cos2^3\theta -1)...(2cos2^{n-1}\theta -1)=
$$
$$\vdots$$
$$=(2cos(2^n\theta)+1)$$

Answer (score 2):

We check if 
$$\frac{2cos(2^n\theta)+1}{2cos\theta+1}= (2cos\theta -1)(2cos2\theta -1)(2cos2^2\theta -1)...(2cos2^{n-1}\theta -1)$$
holds for n=1.
Which is 
$$
\frac{2cos(2\theta)+1}{2cos(\theta)+1}=2cos(\theta)-1
$$
we reformulate this as
$$
2cos(2\theta)+1=(2cos(\theta)+1)(2cos(\theta)-1)
$$
or
$$
2cos(2\theta)+1=4cos^2(\theta)-1
$$
recall 
$2cos^2x-1=cos(2x)$ which gives us $2cos^2x=cos(2x)+1$.

so we have
$$
2cos(2\theta)+1=2(cos(2\theta)+1)-1
$$
so 
$$
2cos(2\theta)+1=2cos(2\theta)+1
$$
So now assume this holds for some n=k, thus we assume
$$
$$
$$\frac{2cos(2^k\theta)+1}{2cos\theta+1}= (2cos\theta -1)(2cos2\theta -1)(2cos2^2\theta -1)...(2cos2^{k-1}\theta -1)$$ holds;
then show it holds for n=k+1.